# Access files using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i'm trying to access to files inside the folder selected by the but the `listFiles()` return null always.
this my code.

```
    private void RequestSAFPermission(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
}




@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;
    Uri treeUri = data.getData();
    DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);
    grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), treeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    Uri docUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(treeUri,
            DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(treeUri));
    path = getPath(getBaseContext(), docUri);
    File file = new File(path);
    File[] files = file.listFiles();

}
```

`getPath()` is from [here](https://gist.github.com/asifmujteba/d89ba9074bc941de1eaa#file-asfurihelper)

Comment: Delete `getPath()`. Pass the `Uri` you got from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()`. Use it to traverse the document tree.

Comment: `grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), treeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
` Remove that line. You cannot grant anything.

Comment: @blackapps but isn't this how to get access to the folder selected by the user

Comment: No delete them and you will see that they do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your time, anyway how can i get the `listFiles()` of the subdirectory that was selected by the user.

Comment: when the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` restart permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pickedDir.listFiles()` instead.