# Accessing Android USB Mass Storage Using Delphi

Tags: android, delphi

I am trying to write an Android App in Delphi 10.4 (primarily for AndroidTV) using Delphi which can read or write files from/to USB mass storage. I can see the files using FileManager App, but have failed to see them with my App. I found a library on GitHub (Libaums) which would appear to do all I want and much more, but is written in a mixture of Kotlin, Java, and C, which would appear to be very difficult to integrate with Delphi.

Edit: The paths I have tried include: GetDataDirectory(), GetRootDirectory(), GetExternalStorageDirectory(),GetSysExternalStorageDirectory(), GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(), /mnt/usb001, /mnt/usb002, /mnt/androidwritable, /mnt/user.

The device in mind currently uses SDK 28, but I would like a solution that would still work on later versions.

All my attempts to get file paths report non-existent, which I take to mean I have a permissions problem. Can anyone:

(1) Advise which file path to request?

(2) How to obtain the relevant permissions?

TIA

Comment: Please tell which paths you tried or how you tried to get a path.

Comment: Do you know the Kastri framework for Delphi? Afaik, it should have what you need.

Comment: @blackapps - please see list in edit above.

Comment: @Delphi Coder 2: Have never encountered Kastri before - looks promising - thanks

Comment: You should use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user pick the drive or a folder on it.

Comment: @ blackapps - thanks for the suggestion - it appears to do exactly what I want, using the code in [link]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70039163/access-files-using-action-open-document-tree), but so far I have failed to successfully convert the code in "onActivityResult" to extract a list of files with their paths. Any help would be much appreciated - Ted